# set default value for angular select from json

Tags: angularjs

Iam not able to set default value to select using angular

```
<span ng-init="key = viewChecklist.type">
 <select ng-model="key" ng-options="key as value for (key, value) in checklist_type"/>
</span>
```

Checklist type JSON is

```
$scope.checklist_type = {
 1:"Product Delivery",
 2:"Quality Analysis"
}
```

and this needs to be matched with type of viewChecklist

```
$scope.viewChecklist = {
  id: 1, 
  checklist_name: "Test", 
  type: "2"
}
```

Comment: what is your problem?it work correctly!!

Comment: strange, it works for me http://plnkr.co/edit/tKcfu81oNRwmPBgy34ji

Comment: What version of angular you are using?

Comment: issue i figured out was that the key value needs to be string and not integer..once changing it to string it worked. Thanks all :)

Answer (score 0):

What i understood is that you are not able to set default selected item in your dropdown. you can use ng-init like below:

```
<select ng-model="key" ng-options="key as value for (key, value) in checklist_type" ng-init="key='key[0]'"/>
```

Update:
In controller you need to set the which value you want to set as selected. In my blow example i have added this line instead on "ng-init":

```
$scope.selectedName = $scope.names[1];
```

Here is the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kyaqzgo6/2/

Comment: Thanks it worked, just had to change key value to string